# cerrar APP android desde una clase

Tags: android

he creado una clase

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    Activity activity;
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval,Activity m_activity) {
        super(startTime, interval);
        activity = m_activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage("TERMINO SU TIEMPO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        valoresGenerales.banderaCountDownTimer = false;
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if( millisUntilFinished/1000 == 35)
        {
            FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage("SI no usa  en " + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " segundos se cerrara automáticamente.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        if( millisUntilFinished/1000 == 10)
        {
            FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage("SI no usa  en " + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " segundos se cerrara automáticamente.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }


    }
}
```

como sabran  MyCountDownTimer.. es un contador hacia atras.. lo que intento hacer es .. cerrar mi app cuando este contador llegue a 0 y entre al onFinish() puse el codigo

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

pero haciendo pruebas me di ceunta que solo cierra un solo activity (el que esta visible) y abre el actMain (principal) de manera automatica.

pero estoy mi app tiene varios activitys que se abren (activity 1 abre al activity2 que asu vez abre al activity 3 etc) eso quiere decir que tengo mas de un activity en uso y  por lo tanto el código no me ayuda.

que código me podría servir ???

muchas gracias.

Comment: Alguna de tus actividades abre todas las demás?

Comment: si.. mas de una.. por ejemplo tengo un activity de un listado que al seleccionar abre la edición de ese ítem .. este ítem puede tener otro activity que usa para registrar x cosas. .  gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fue fácil hacerlo, con este código

```
act.finishAffinity();
 act.startActivity(new Intent(act, actMain.class));
```

donde act.. es el activity actual (cualquier pantalla)

y el

```
actMain.class
```

es para mi caso la pantalla de iniciar sesión (pantalla principal)

Answer (score 5):

Te doy una solución en la cual tus actividades tiene que extender de una actividad "padre", por ejemplo, suponemos tener estas 3 Activities, las 3 deben extender de la actividad padre `ParentActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity {

public class Activity2 extends ParentActivity {

public class Activity3 extends ParentActivity {
```

Este sería el código de la actividad `ParentActivity`, la cual cuenta con 2 métodos `setActivity()` para agregar la referencia de la actividad a un `List` y `quitApp()` que busca todas las actividades que fueron guardadas en la lista y las finaliza:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();

    public void setActivity(Activity act){
        activities.add(act);
    }

    public void quitApp(){
        for(Activity a : activities){
            a.finish();
        }
    }    

}
```

Dentro de tus actividades tienes que agregar la línea:

```
setActivity(this);
```

para agregar la actividad al `List`.

y en cualquiera puedes llamar el método:

```
quitApp();
```

con el cual cerrara todas las `Activities` registradas en el `List` definido en `ParentActivity`.

En tu código podrías llamar  `quitApp()` dentro de `onFinish()` para cerrar todas las Actividades:

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
       quitApp();
    }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias .. pero en mi caso . no estoy en un activity sino en class   -->  class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer

Comment: Te sirve igual, ya que lo que puedes hacer es a esta clase en lugar de decirle que le pasas una Activity, le pasas una ParentActivity (cambiar el tipo del atributo activity),  y luego en el onFinish(), haces activity.quitApp()

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se agote el tiempo, haz que se cargue la actividad principal encima de todas las demás.

```
//Enviar itent para cerrar app
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("SalirApp", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

y en tu actividad principal en `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
  if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("SalirApp", false)){
      finish();
      return;
  }
```

Comment: Lo que desea el OP es que si abre varias, todas se cierren al mismo tiempo... :(

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente sea tarde para responder, pero por si alguien más tiene la misma pregunta.

Lo único que debes de hacer es poner el método

```
finishAffinity
```

Por ejemplo, si tienes un button para cerrar toda la app, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
btnCerrarApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finishAffinity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nunca es tarde para aportar, toda ayuda es bienvenida. Saludos